# PHP Input issue

Tags: php

I send raw data to server and I want to get it via `file_get_contents('php://input')` but it always gives me `null` value.

What is the problem?

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
var_dump($data); // NULL
```

Comment: show whole code.

Comment: there is not any problem code. This problem starts after change my server.

Comment: enable `error_reporting` then check again. Might be `file_get_content` is off on your server.

Comment: how can in set on file_get_content?

Comment: if shared hosting then there is an option in cpanel otherwise check `php.ini`

Comment: So, what's the request? Why would you expect any unprocessed input?

Comment: it is dedicated server.

Comment: Request is get via postman

Comment: i research it and i find always_populate_raw_post_data. But this deprecated in php 7

Comment: _“i research it and i find always_populate_raw_post_data”_ - if your request is a GET request as you said in the previous comment, then this setting has nothing to do with what you want in the first place - it is for raw _POST_ data, nomen est omen. And `php://input` gives access to the request _body_ - which GET requests usually don’t have in the first place, so `php://input` _should_ be empty here. If you need access to anything “raw” about a standard GET request, then go look inside `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Do you use enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form when sending that? If yes, just remove it. Because it's not working with the php://input and makes it null.

Comment: Did you use ```php://input``` in the case of POST requests?